# Can we change the behaviour of this keyword and pass element sibling instead of clicked item itself

Tags: jquery

```
$('#txtBox1, #txtBox2').siblings(':button').on('click', function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

At the moment I get this as output,

```
<input type='button'...
```

Is there anyway I could get textbox instead of button ?

buttons are sibling to #textBox1 and #textBox2

when buttons are clicked, I want to get crossponding textbox as "this"

**Why**

***Because I already have a function which is using this as textbox, so I want to use same method here, so all changes must be where I am adding events.***

**Edit**

I want to pass textbox as "this" to function button click event will call, atm its sending input, I can change function and get the sibling but that is not what I am after here.

Repeating myself, is it possible to do such thing without making changes to click event function :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the siblings that are not buttons of clicked button to get object of those two textboxes or target siblings of type text:

```
$('#txtBox1, #txtBox2').siblings(':button').on('click', function () {
  console.log($(this).siblings(':text')); //elements of type text
  //or
  console.log($(this).siblings().not(':button')); //elements that are not button
});
```

Comment: that's the point, I can get textbox in the function using $(this).siblings()... but is it possible to get it as "this"

Comment: @PleaseTeach: `this` is object of clicked button you have to traverse to those element for targeting them.

Comment: not exactly what I wanted, but for now I will accept it as what I want is not possible at this point, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get crossponding textbox as "this"

That's not possible, but you can use [jQuery's traversal methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) to find the corresponding `input` field. E.g.

```
$(this).siblings('input')
```

> I already have a function which is using this as textbox

You can [call that function and set `this` explicitly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to the correct DOM element:

```
existingFunction.call($(this).siblings('input').get(0));
// inside existingFunction, `this` will refer to `$(this).siblings('input').get(0)`
// i.e. the input DOM element
```

---

> Repeating myself, is it possible to do such thing without making changes to click event function :-)

Repeating myself as well, it's not possible. `this` inside the event handler will refer to the element the handler was bound to, which is the button element(s).